# Zabbix Log monitoring: How to get notifications such that all error logs appear in one mail

Tags: logging, monitoring, zabbix

I am using Zabbix to monitor a log file. The objective is to capture all the lines which have "ERROR" keyword in the log file and send a notification to me

**The content of the log file is:**

20160905:154718 ERROR: there is an error...
20160905:154718 ERROR: hello
20160905:154718 ERROR: hello again
20160905:154718 ERROR: bye

**So, ideally I want to get the following in my mail:**

Trigger: Error appearing in the logs
Trigger status: PROBLEM
Trigger severity: Not classified
Trigger URL:

Item values:

1. Dummy Log (Centos-remote-agent:logrt[/root/test_log/test.log,"ERROR"]): 20160905:154718 ERROR: there is an error....
2. Dummy Log (Centos-remote-agent:logrt[/root/test_log/test.log,"ERROR"]): 20160905:154718 ERROR: hello
3. Dummy Log (Centos-remote-agent:logrt[/root/test_log/test.log,"ERROR"]): 20160905:154718 ERROR: hello again
4. Dummy Log (Centos-remote-agent:logrt[/root/test_log/test.log,"ERROR"]): 20160905:154718 ERROR: bye

**In the front end, I have configured the item as:**

Name: Dummy Log 
Type: Zabbix agent (active) 
Key: logrt[/root/test_log/test.log,"ERROR"] 
Type of information: Log 
Log Time Format: yyyyMMdd:hhmmss

**My trigger expression is:**

{Centos-remote-agent:logrt[/root/test_log/test.log,"ERROR"].regexp(ERROR)}=1

**However, i get the first line of the log file, in my mail:**

Trigger: Error appearing in the logs
Trigger status: PROBLEM
Trigger severity: Not classified
Trigger URL:

Item values:

1. Dummy Log (Centos-remote-agent:logrt[/root/test_log/test.log,"ERROR"]): 20160905:154718 ERROR: there is an error....
2. *UNKNOWN* (*UNKNOWN*:*UNKNOWN*): *UNKNOWN*
3. *UNKNOWN* (*UNKNOWN*:*UNKNOWN*): *UNKNOWN*

Original event ID: 133

I feel that my trigger expression might be incorrect. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, Zabbix doesn't really support that, and your expression is probably correct. The multiple item values you see refer to the trigger expression - for example, if your trigger was checking two items like `itemA.last()>0 and itemB.last()<0`, the first line would show the value of `itemA`, and the second line would show the value of `itemB`.

You can try something like `{{HOST.NAME}:{ITEM.KEY}.last(#2)}` to show the second last value, but even if that would work and you would add lines up to `last(#4)`, you would get an email on every single value, with previous values included as well - so assuming that most recent values are at the top, you would get 4 emails like this:

Email 1

```
bye
```

Email 2

```
hello again
bye
```

Email 3

```
hello
hello again
bye
```

Email 4

```
there is an error...
hello
hello again
bye
```